# How to properly add '?i#efix' to a font path in rails?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, font-face

It is [recommended](http://www.fontspring.com/blog/fixing-ie9-font-face-problems) to add `?#iefix` to the end of .eot font paths to fix yet another IE erratic behaviour :

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyWebFont';
    src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
         url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
         url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
         url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
    }
```

**Is it possible to do that using `asset_path`, but without an ugly** `+ "?#iefix"` **hack ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that `asset_path` **already takes this into account**. So:

```
asset_path 'webfont.eot?#iefix'
```

does work out-of-the-box ! My bad...

Answer (score 2):

This is how I use it in my projects. Works great in all browsers. It is important to break it to two `@font-face` declarations.

My `fonts.scss`:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Webfont';
  src: font_url('webfont.eot?') format('embedded-opentype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Webfont';
  src: font_url('webfont.woff') format('woff'),
       font_url('webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
       font_url('webfont.svg#Webfont') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Please note that if you want to use the SASS helper `font_url`, you have to have your fonts placed under the `assets/fonts` directory.

From my experience adding just `?` to the font path for >=IE8 instead of anything starting `?#` works. But, as mentioned in the beginning, keep the `@font-face` declaration for IE separate. For the use in SASS helper, just place it at the end of the asset name. It does not break the helper processing.

Comment: sorry, but this does not answer the question, which is about `asset_path` and string concatenation.

Comment: I am sorry too. I overlooked the question below your code. I added the SASS helpers in my code example. Hopefully this is will help you solver the problem.

Comment: Thanks, i will try this monday -though i'm not sure SASS is allowed in this project i'm working on. BTW, could you explain why is it important to break apart the font declarations ?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

**Important:**
Please verify your font name is added correctly in all places.
And please verify whether all font face files are available.

**Add in Production.rb:**

```
config.host_path = "http://---site url--"
```

**Add following in CSS:**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Webfont';
    src: url('<%= Rails.application.config.host_path %>/assets/fonts/Webfont.eot');
    src: url('<%= Rails.application.config.host_path %>/assets/fonts/Webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('<%= Rails.application.config.host_path %>/assets/fonts/Webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('<%= Rails.application.config.host_path %>/assets/fonts/Webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('<%= Rails.application.config.host_path %>/assets/fonts/Webfont.svg#Webfont') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

---

if you dont want hard coded font files path, then just use following in **css**.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Webfont';
    src: url('Webfont.eot');
    src: url('Webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('Webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('Webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('Webfont.svg#Webfont') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

We need to specify full URL path for access font files.
I hope it will help..

Comment: thanks, but i'm not really fond of the idea of not using the asset_path helper. Kind of breaks the whole point of using helpers instead of hardcoded paths...

Comment: you can try my update. Im providing two answers. First one is hard coded font path and next one is as your need.